# How to search in a field of a table, the elements that have the letter r and then the s, but in that order?

Tags: sql

I'm running this but I don't respect the order of first the r and then the s

```
SELECT TITULO,PRECIO_ORI, EDICION
FROM LIBRO
WHERE TITULO LIKE '%R%S%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want any value strat with r then s in the beginning, your code will be:

```
... WHERE TITULO LIKE 'RS%'
```

But if want any value containing the 'rs' even in the beginning or anywhere else, your code will be:

```
... WHERE TITULO LIKE '%RS%'
```

Comment: sure, but they do not have to be glued, example should find RiderS but not SpideR

Comment: Try but, % between them '%R%S%'

Comment: It does not work, the order in which I put the letters does not respect me